# Why there are eight bytes pad in the stack frame of main function?

Tags: go, assembly

```golang
package main

func main() {
  var x int32 = 1
  nop(x)
}

//go:noinline
func nop(x int32) {}
```

**Go version: go1.16.15 windows/amd64**

I wrote above code and compiled it into assembly with `go1.16.15 tool compile -S -N -l main.go` for truly understanding Go functions call.

The following is the assembly code of nop function:

```
"".nop STEXT nosplit size=1 args=0x8 locals=0x0 funcid=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:9)        TEXT    "".nop(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-8
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:9)        FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:9)        FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:9)        RET
```

Obviously, the nop function returns directly without doing anything. It only has a `int32` type parameter, but we can see the `argsize` is 8 bytes in the assembly:

TEXT    "".nop(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-***8***

**Question1: Why the `argsize` is 8 bytes not 4 bytes?**

The following is the assembly code of main function:

```
"".main STEXT size=73 args=0x0 locals=0x18 funcid=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:3)        TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $24-0
        ;; ...omitted stack-split prologue...
        0x0016 00022 (main.go:3)        SUBQ    $24, SP
        0x001a 00026 (main.go:3)        MOVQ    BP, 16(SP)
        0x001f 00031 (main.go:3)        LEAQ    16(SP), BP
        0x0024 00036 (main.go:3)        FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0024 00036 (main.go:3)        FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0024 00036 (main.go:4)        MOVL    $1, "".x+12(SP)
        0x002c 00044 (main.go:5)        MOVL    $1, (SP)
        0x0033 00051 (main.go:5)        PCDATA  $1, $0
        0x0033 00051 (main.go:5)        CALL    "".nop(SB)
        0x0038 00056 (main.go:6)        MOVQ    16(SP), BP
        0x003d 00061 (main.go:6)        ADDQ    $24, SP
        0x0041 00065 (main.go:6)        RET
        ;; ...omitted stack-split epilogue...
```

I drawn a picture of stack according to the assembly code:
[stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHN1b.png)

**Question2: I find there are confusing 8 bytes in the stack, why do these 8 bytes exist?**

I think memory alignment causes the above phenomenon, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does the Go ABI say? I don't know the Go calling convention but questions about the size of locals/params are routinely asked here and the answer is always the same: to keep the stack pointer aligned as required by the ABI. This may not apply to Go, but the first step would be to prove or disprove this. Go assembly is still pretty high level, you should see the real machine code. At the Go assembly level there's nothing wrong with rounding frame sizes to 8 and eventually omitting setting up a frame for empty functions.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for your comment. Go uses registers and stack for passing arguments and results from 1.17, but before that, only the stack. Unfortunately, I can't find the ABI doc berfore 1.17 :( .